# Error de script/rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Estoy desarrollando un plugin para Redmine en ruby on reals. Al lanzar el comando que me genera el comando

`bundle exec ruby script/rails generate redmine_plugin_model plugin_prueba prueba question:string yes:integer no:integer` me da el siguiente error en consola

`ruby: No such file or directory -- script/rails (LoadError)`

Comment: y si usas solo `rails` en vez de `script/rails`?

Comment: Correcto es la solución para versiones de rails posteriores a la 3. Gracias por la ayuda

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Debes usar:

```
bundle exec ruby rails
```

De hecho, en nuevas versiones de rails ya no existe la carpeta `script/`, viniendo ahora todos los binstubs en `bin/`, por lo tanto:

```
bundle exec ruby bin/rails
```

también es otra opción de ejecución.